# How to display particular image by clicking one flatlist images in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a flat list that returns multiple images. but I want to show an image on another view by clicking FlatList image. when I click on FlatList image that particular image will be shown in another view. how to do please suggest.

Here is my FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.images}
  renderItem={this.renderGalleryImage}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  horizontal={true}
/>;

renderGalleryImage = ({ item }) => {
  return <Image source={item} style={styles.moreImg} />;
};
```

and here is the view where I want to display

```
<View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this problem in several ways; The easiest way is to wrap the `renderGalleryImage` return statement with a **Touchable** primitive and add an `onPress` event handler.

You can use the `useState` hook in tandem to save the selected `Image` from the FlatList.

*Here's a sample code snippet.*

```js
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");

renderGalleryImage = ({ item }) => {
  const setImage = () => setSelectedItem(item);
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedBack onPress={() => setSelectedItem(item)}>
      <Image source={item} style={styles.moreImg} />;
    </TouchableWithoutFeedBack>
  );
};

return <View>{selectedItem && <Image source={{ uri: selectedItem }} />}</View>;
```

Note: If you're using **class-based** components, follow this approach:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedImage: "",
  };

  renderGalleryImage = ({ item }) => {
    const setImage = () => this.setState({ selectedImage: item.image });
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={setImage} style={{ margin: 30 }}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item.image }}
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const renderImage = () => (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: this.state.selectedImage }}
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100,borderColor:'red',borderWidth:1 }}
        />
      </View>
    );

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList data={users} renderItem={this.renderGalleryImage} />;
        <Text>Selected Image</Text>
        {renderImage()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the link to a working demo on [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@ajinkabeer/flatlist).

Comment: can you tell me how to add a red border which is a selected image?

Comment: I want to add border in flat list image which one is selected